# Netty 4 doesnt handle message

Tags: java, netty

I have an little problem with netty.
Currently, netty doesnt handle messages, the channelRead() method isnt executed, but the logger says netty received the message and the channelReadComplete() method is also executed.

```
try {
            //logger
            Logger.getRootLogger().debug("initialize channel pipeline.");

            //use gzip compression
            //pipeline.addLast("deflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
            //pipeline.addLast("inflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));

            //log events
            pipeline.addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));

            //message encoder and decoder
            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MessageEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MessageDecoder());

            //create message handler
            final MessageLookupHandler handler = new MessageLookupHandler() {
                @Override
                protected void initActions(Map<Byte, MessageAction> map) {
                    if (map == null) {
                        Logger.getRootLogger().warn("LookUp Table is null.");
                    }

                    try {
                        Logger.getRootLogger().debug("initialize actions.");

                        //login action
                        map.put(LoginAction.MESSAGE_TYPE, new LoginAction(LoginServer.this.userSystem, LoginServer.this.sessionClient));

                        //register action
                        map.put(RegisterAction.MESSAGE_TYPE, new RegisterAction(LoginServer.this.userSystem));

                        //mail activation action
                        map.put(ActivationAction.MESSAGE_TYPE, new ActivationAction(LoginServer.this.userSystem));

                        for (Map.Entry<Byte,MessageAction> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                            Logger.getRootLogger().debug("registered action: " + entry.getKey());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //because netty doesnt catch exception in constructors, print stacktrace here
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void exceptionCaught (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
                    //exception handling
                    cause.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

            //add handler
            pipeline.addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                    Logger.getRootLogger().debug("channel read.");
                    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                }

                @Override
                public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MessageLookupHandler.class.getName()).info("channel read complete.");
                    //ctx.flush();
                }
            });

            pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

MessageEncoder:

```
public class MessageEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Message>
{
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception
    {
        out.writeInt(Message.HEADER_LENGHT + msg.content().readableBytes());
        out.writeByte(msg.getType());
        out.writeByte(msg.getVersion());
        out.writeBytes(msg.content());
    }
}
```

MessageDecoder:

```
public class MessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder
{   
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception
    {
        if (in.readableBytes() < 4) return;
        in.markReaderIndex();

        int length = in.readInt();
        if (in.readableBytes() < length)
        {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }

        byte type = in.readByte();
        byte version = in.readByte();
        ByteBuf content = in.slice(in.readerIndex(), length - Message.HEADER_LENGHT);
        in.skipBytes(length - Message.HEADER_LENGHT);

        // increment refcount since content is a slice of in and ByteToMessageDecoder will release in
        content.retain();

        Message message = new Message(type, version, content);
        out.add(message);
    }
}
```

Logger Output:

```
33808 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG root  - initialize channel pipeline.
33808 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG root  - initialize actions.
33808 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG root  - registered action: 1
33809 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG root  - registered action: 2
33809 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG root  - registered action: 3
33810 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  - [id: 0x31c22087, /127.0.0.1:53164 => /127.0.0.1:3001] REGISTERED
33810 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  - [id: 0x31c22087, /127.0.0.1:53164 => /127.0.0.1:3001] ACTIVE
33883 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  - [id: 0x31c22087, /127.0.0.1:53164 => /127.0.0.1:3001] RECEIVED: 200B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 22 62 69 72 74 68 64 61 79 22 3a 7b 22 6d 6f |{"birthday":{"mo|
|00000010| 6e 74 68 22 3a 31 2c 22 79 65 61 72 22 3a 31 39 |nth":1,"year":19|
|00000020| 39 36 2c 22 64 61 79 22 3a 31 7d 2c 22 6d 61 69 |96,"day":1},"mai|
|00000030| 6c 22 3a 22 74 65 73 74 40 70 65 6e 74 61 71 75 |l":"test@*******|
|00000040| 69 6e 2e 63 6f 6d 22 2c 22 70 61 73 73 77 6f 72 |******","passwor|
|00000050| 64 48 61 73 68 22 3a 22 36 65 59 7a 43 58 71 35 |dHash":"********|
|00000060| 7a 72 50 6b 6a 73 50 33 44 75 4b 2b 75 6b 48 51 |****************|
|00000070| 58 56 51 67 37 2b 35 64 71 46 2b 58 32 58 41 46 |****************|
|00000080| 63 6e 57 48 2f 61 4d 2b 39 50 38 6a 49 67 69 50 |****************|
|00000090| 54 48 6e 6f 45 7a 7a 4a 7a 5a 38 31 45 76 54 54 |****************|
|000000a0| 6f 77 50 4c 32 31 76 46 68 55 46 61 41 41 3d 3d |****************|
|000000b0| 22 2c 22 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 74 65 |","username":"te|
|000000c0| 73 74 75 73 65 72 22 7d                         |stuser"}        |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
Okt 19, 2015 9:00:35 PM com.pentaquin.core.network.MessageLookupHandler channelReadComplete
INFORMATION: channel read complete.
```

Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What does MessageDecoder do ? I suspect it not handles the read messages correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The encoder converts the byte array into our message object and decoder converts message object into byte array.

Comment: I have edited the first post and added the code.

Comment: I have added an logger output in encoder and decoder methods and the encode() and decode() method was executed.